# How to split text int array of sentences based on ?, ! and . in Java?

Tags: java, string, sentence

How to split text int array of sentences based on ?, ! and . in Java?

For example I want to store sentences from a string into a oversized array. myArray[0] = 1st sentence, myArray[1] = 2nd sentence and etc/

Comment: Is there anything you have done to try to solve this problem? We will be more willing to answer your question if you tell us what you have tried so far. (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [FAQ])

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.split(regex)` method, like this:

```
String[] sentendes = text.split("(?<=[.!?])\\s*");
```

Using *lookbehind* should help you preserve the punctuation mark after the sentence.

Here is a small [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/lyCNVO).

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
String[] myArray = "sentence! sentence. sentence?".split("(<=[\\!\\?\\.])\\s*")
```

Explanation:

```
(<=       lookbehind, to preserve punctuation as in @dasblinkenlight's answer
[         start category (which would be !, ?, or .)
\\!\\?\\. punctuation (must be escaped)
]         end category
)         end lookbehind
\\s*      any amount of whitespace
```